C# gRPC client to Publish platform events
I've found an example for subscribing to Salesforce platform events in C# but have yet to find one for publishing.  I took a stab using the java/python examples I get no errors on the publish and I can see my event making it to the Platform events screen incrementing the:"High-Volume Platform Event Hourly Publishing Allocation"
the High-Volume Platform Event and Change Event Daily Delivery Allocation does not increment
My subscribing trigger never fires.  If I fire off the platform event from jetstream, everything works.  I've set up AutomatedProcess User logs and no log is created.  Permissions on trigger align with the authenticating user. I assume I'm doing something wrong with how I'm encoding my event such that it isn't able to be picked up?
I'm using the protobuff file from the samples and have left out the auth stuff - I'm connecting to SF no problem
private ProducerEvent CreateProducerEvents(string schemaId, string message, string teId)
{

    --From proto generated file
    ProducerEvent producerEvent = new ProducerEvent();

    Travel_Episode_Comment_Event__e teComment = new Travel_Episode_Comment_Event__e();
    teComment.Travel_Episode_Id__c = teId;
    teComment.Clinical_User__c = "Joe Fish";
    teComment.Message__c = message;
   
    string obj = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(teComment);
       
    byte[] objByte = AvroConvert.Json2Avro(obj);
    producerEvent.Payload = ByteString.CopyFrom(objByte);  
    producerEvent.SchemaId = schemaId;
    producerEvent.Id = "2"; -- tried randomizing this
    return producerEvent;         
}
 
public async Task Publish(string message)
{
    var source = new CancellationTokenSource();
    string platformEventName = "/event/Travel_Episode_Comment_Event__e";
    var topic = GetTopicByName(platformEventName);    

    PublishRequest pr = new PublishRequest();    

    pr.Events.Add(CreateProducerEvents(topic.SchemaId, message, "a0HOu000002MUfsMAG"));
    pr.TopicName = platformEventName;

    PublishResponse pubRes = _client.Publish(request: pr, headers: _metadata, cancellationToken: source.Token);

    Google.Protobuf.Collections.RepeatedField<PublishResult> results = pubRes.Results;
    string errors = "";
    foreach (var result in results)
    {
        errors += " " +  result.Error;
    }
    --No errors and I get a replayID + other id's back
    Console.WriteLine(errors);
}

--Generated from the schema pulled back from SF
public class Travel_Episode_Comment_Event__e
 {
     /// <summary>
     /// CreatedDate:DateTime
     /// </summary>
     public long CreatedDate => DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks;
     /// <summary>
     /// CreatedBy:EntityId
     /// </summary>
     public string CreatedById => "005Hu00000PJKXWIA5";
     /// <summary>
     /// Data:Text:00NOu000001881R
     /// </summary>
     public string? Travel_Episode_Id__c { get; set; }
     /// <summary>
     /// Data:Text:00NOu0000018833
     /// </summary>
     public string? Clinical_User__c { get; set; }
     /// <summary>
     /// Data:Text:00NOu000001884f
     /// </summary>
     public string? Message__c { get; set; }
 }

 public TopicInfo GetTopicByName(string platformEventName)
 {
     TopicRequest topicRequest = new TopicRequest
     {
         TopicName = platformEventName
     };

     return _client.GetTopic(request: topicRequest, headers: _metadata);
 }

 public SchemaInfo GetSchemaById(string schemaId)
 {
     SchemaRequest schemaRequest = new SchemaRequest
     {
         SchemaId = schemaId
     };

     return _client.GetSchema(request: schemaRequest, headers: _metadata);
 }


JsonConvert.SerializeObject is Newtonsoft.JsonConvert whereas the official doc on GH recommends Apache Avro or AvroConvert. Try that.

I’m using jsonconvert to get ghe json string from the entity then using avroConvert on the json string.  I didn’t see a way to go from entity to avro byte[] conversion directly

AvroConvert.Serialize works on objects, check the docs.

Unfortunately, same behavior.
